# ¿Como capturar los usuarios relacionados a una tabla una vez?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

como puedo hacer para seleccionar todos los usuarios que esten relacionados a una tabla, se que se puede usar un join pero el problema es que por cada entrada con el id del usuario se repetira varias veces el nombre.

Para poner en contexto tengo una tabla trabajos y otra tabla users, la cosa es que en la tabla trabajos enlazo un usuario y un trabajo, posteriormente hago un foreach para que mande un email con cada trabajo al usuario de ese email, el problema es que no todos los usuarios tienen trabajos, lo que genera errores y evita que mande el resto de correo a los demas usuarios, entonces quisiera saber como puedo hacer para capturar a todos los usuarios que solo tengan un registro en la tabla.

En este momento mi consulta esta asi:

```
$systems = User::where('codarea','>',0)
     ->get();
```

Pero esto me devuelve:

```
1 usuario usuario@gmail.com 
2 usuariodos usuariodos@gmail.com 
3 usuariotres usuariotres@gmail.com
```

Donde como el usuariodos no tiene trabajos asignados y me aparece el error  Trying to get property 'email' of non-object.

Ahora uso:

```
$systems = User::where('codarea','>',0)
         ->join('patrabajo', 'patrabajo.usuario', '=', 'users.id')
         ->get();
```

Y ahora no tengo errores, pero sucede que:

```
1 usuario usuario@gmail.com 
3 usuariotres usuariotres@gmail.com
3 usuariotres usuariotres@gmail.com
3 usuariotres usuariotres@gmail.com
1 usuario usuario@gmail.com
```

Provocando que mande 3 emails al usuariotres y dos emails al usuario. Que puedo hacer? espero puedan ayudarme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si solo estás obteniendo estás 2 columnas, entonces puedes:

- Indicarlo de forma explícita en el `SELECT`
- Hacer un agrupamiento para que renglones con valores iguales se fusionen

Consulta:

```
$systems = User::select('columna1', 'columna2')
         ->join('patrabajo', 'patrabajo.usuario', '=', 'users.id')
         ->where('codarea','>',0)
         ->groupBy('columna1', 'columna2')
         ->get();
```